# windows 7 can't add printer redirected port

Tags: windows, redirect, printing, port, redmon

I would like to use RedMon in order to redirected printing data to my application as input.

I installed RedMon but when I want to add printer port there is no such option as "Redirected Port". I can select only from these types of ports:
1. Local Port
3. Standard TCP/IP Port

How can I add Redirected Port?

Answer (score 0):

Comes late, but try [Creating a free PDFWriter using Ghostscript](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSWriter/GSWriter.html)